# Scrambled menu when resizing

Tags: html, css

When the browser page is full size, the menu is centered in the middle page (That's the correct position) but when resizing the window, the menu isn't visible anymore except by scrolling to the max right of the site. I looked it up to be a responsiveness problem, however i failed to solve it. Any ideas??

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
            <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)"><button onclick="myFunction()">AA</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">A </button></li>
            <li id="item3">B      </li>
            <li id="item4">C      </li>
            <li id="item5">D      </li>
            <li id="item6">E      </li>
            <li id="item7">F      </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

css:

```
lu, li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;    
    border-style: none;
}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;

}



.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 725px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;  
}
```

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bdptr0nf/2/)?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0 auto;` in `.menu`

Remove `left: 725px;` from `.menu li`

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/61capLqy/

```css
lu, li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;    
    border-style: none;
}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;
    margin:0 auto;

}



.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;  
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
            <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)"><button onclick="myFunction()">AA</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">A </button></li>
            <li id="item3">B      </li>
            <li id="item4">C      </li>
            <li id="item5">D      </li>
            <li id="item6">E      </li>
            <li id="item7">F      </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: hey man it worked, however i'm doing an animation to the elements of the menu to move to the left of the screen upon clicking on one of its elements. The feature stopped after i edited based on your saying.